# Deleting lines from binary data

Tags: php, binary

How can I delete some lines("\r\n") from a binary data:
for example if I have $data which is the content of a binary file I'm getting from my database and wanted to delete the first five lines from it.

How can this be done in php?

Comment: Binary data does not have "lines".  It has bytes, and that's about it.  It might have some groups of bytes that form characters that *look* like lines, but treating them as such will cause you all kinds of annoyance.

Comment: There are actually some file formats with ASCII metadata at the beginning using newlines, carriage return or even both as separators so this may well be real text lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Load the file into memory
$fileData = file_get_contents('myfile.bin');

// Split it by CRLF sequences
$fileData = explode("\r\n", $fileData);

// Remove the first 5 lines
$fileData = array_slice($fileData, 5);

// Turn it back into a string
$fileData = implode("\r\n", $fileData);

// Write it back to the file
file_put_contents('myfile.bin', $fileData);
```

Or, in one line:

```
file_put_contents('myfile.bin', implode("\r\n", array_slice(explode("\r\n", file_get_contents('myfile.bin')), 5)));
```

But if you want to do this with "binary data", I would question whether it really is binary data.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to get rid of all empty lines at the start of the string you could use ltrim() [PHP Manual ltrim](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) but if the lines aren't empty and you know you want to get rid of exactly 5 lines then this preg_replace should do the trick:

```
$newData = preg_replace('/(.*)\r\n/', '', $data, 5);
```

[Edit:]
Come to think of it, this might not work for binary data at all but you can give it a try.